# Initializing vector with a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

can we iniitialize a vector in c++ with the fuction of returning type vector.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<int> parseInts(string str) {
    // Complete this function
}

int main() {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    vector<int> integers = parseInts(str); /** here is the problem **/
    for(int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++) {
        cout << integers[i] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes.(need more character)

Comment: yes you can and the move semantics will be used

Comment: `/** here is the problem **/` What problem?

Comment: You need to actually explain what the problem is. This is not a "do it for you" website, despite some of the code dumps people have posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possibile to return a `std::vector` from a function. And with that we can, as said in your words, "Initialize vector with a vector". In C++ we can make use of RVO, Return Value Optimization. You may read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) about copy elision and RVO. Basically it says, that you will not have a problem with copying bytes when returning containers from a function by value. It is now even the recommended way to do so.

So, you can (and should) return a `std::vector` from a function. The compiler will take care that this works in an optimized way.

But first, please see the below example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

std::vector<int> parseInts(std::string str) {

    // Put the string into a stream
    std::istringstream iss{ str };

    // Return the vector of ints 
    return { std::istream_iterator<int>(iss), {} };
}

int main() {
    // Test data
    std::string test{ "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" };

    // Get the vector with the ints
    std::vector ints = parseInts(test);

    // Show output
    for (const int i : ints) 
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

We have a function called `parseInts` consisting of just 2 lines of code.

First, we we put the string into an istringstream. With that, it would be possible to extract int from the new stream, like in

```
std::istringstream iss{ str };
int i1, i2;
iss >> i1 >> i2;
```

The extractor operator >> will "extract" space delimited integer values from the stream (the string).

But, if we look at it, we see, that then we need to know the number of integers in the string, and then repeatedly write ">>". For doing things repeatedly for the same number of items, like integers, we have iterators in C++. With iterators you can iterate over similar elements in a container. If you assume a string to be a container, you can of course iterate over the integers in it. There are iterators available that do this for us.

In the case of a stream, we have the [std::istream_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator). This thing will iterate over all space delimited items of a certain type in the input stream and return the values.

The many values , that this iterator return, can best be stored in a `std::vector`, because it is a dynamically growing container. Ideal for us, becuase we do not know the number of integers in the stream in advance.

If we look at the `std::vector`, we find out that it has a so called range constructor. Please see here: [range constructor (number 5)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

With the range constructor we define a variable of type `std::vector` and initialize it with a "begin" and an "end" iterator. Values in this range, will be put into the vector.

if we define the variable of type `std::vector` in our example, we could write:

```
std::vector<int> intv{ std::istream_iterator<int>(iss), std::istream_iterator<int>() };
```

or

```
std::vector<int> intv( (std::istream_iterator<int>(iss)), std::istream_iterator<int>() );
```

Please not the braces for the first argument. This is necessary to protect against the most vexing parse problem. You do not want to define a function, but a variable.

But we will anyway not use it. Because with uniform initalization and the {}-initializer as the default-initializer. We can use the default the 2nd parameter. Now we could write:

```
std::vector<int> intv(std::istream_iterator<int>(iss), {});
```

So, next, we can make usage of CTAD, [Class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction). Basically, the compiler knows from the parameters in the constructor, what datatype of the container it will construct. So, no need to write it.

Now:

```
std::vector intv(std::istream_iterator<int>(iss), {});
```

This looks already very nice and you could now return the variable intv.

But there is more. The compiler knows the type of the function and what it should return. So, you can use a braced initializer and return that and the compiler knows, that you want to return a `std::vector<int>`

So the final statement is:

```
return { std::istream_iterator<int>(iss), {} };
```

I hope it helps.

And sorry for the long description for the one line of code.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<int> parseInts(string str) {    //this line tells that function will return an integer vector
    vector <int> hello;
    int n,ele;
    cout<<"Enter An Integer:";
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>ele;
        hello.push_back(ele);
    }
    return hello;           //vector named hello returned to main function
}

int main() {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    vector<int> integers = parseInts(str); /** here is the problem **/
    for(int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++) {
        cout << integers[i] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This may cause more confusion than it alleviates. Normally when you parse you don't ask the user to tell you how many items are going to be parsed out of the input, and if you do, you give a more descriptive prompt than "Enter an integer:". It's done by the software automatically.

Comment: @JohnFilleau,   As I can see the user is trying to understand a problem to how return a vector from a function, the problem may be of hackerrank.com. where he has to return a vector.

Comment: @hegel5000 he did not asked what computation we have to do with ```str```.

Comment: Yes.  You could have also done absolutely no parsing and returned the first twenty Fibonacci numbers.  But if you're learning to code, you want to try to at least think about why a particular function name and signature is chosen (or change the signature to best describe the code inside).

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<int> parseInts(string str) {
    vector <int> hello;
    int n,ele;
    stringstream geek(str);              // object from the class stringstream 
    geek>>n;               //converts to int
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>ele;
        hello.push_back(ele);
    }
    return hello;
}

int main() {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    vector<int> integers = parseInts(str); /** here is the problem **/
    for(int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++) {
        cout << integers[i] << "\n";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When answering a question for a beginner it generally helps to give an explanation of what your code does. A code dump only helps someone who wants to copy-paste an answer into an online judge or autograder and move on, and doesn't care about learning. This answer helps neither the beginner who wants to learn, nor the lazy student who doesn't.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Nice downvote explanation. Whether you yourself actually downvoted or not is irrelevant. (I did not.) So nice to see the desperate plea for explaining comments covered for once.

Comment: Thanks @Yunnosch, I try. Sometimes I don't explain my downvotes, but I try.

Comment: By the way Garvit Joshi, did you give up on your other, even more downvoted answer? You might want to delete it then.

Comment: @Yunnosch , It was my first answer , rather would keep it for my memories though. sorry i am not good with explaining codes. Hey john , and i am too a beginner, you may have also started from this position, would you like the community if you get so many downvotes.